# Not getting duplicated records for someone

Tags: php, mysql

I have a racerecords table where the race records are kept. When someone finishes the race no matter the finish time or position is, the records is being inserted to table. I want to get top 5 best racers not top 5 best times.

Please help me with the sql query. By the way the columns are id, holder, rec_time, time, position

Comment: what is *rec_time*, and *time*? Which difference there is between them? Also notice you did not put a race_id, and in your comment to my attempt at answering you did use a *race_id* field. Can you elaborate more clearly your question?

Comment: rec_time is the race time and the time is the unix time stamp. Let's say we have 5 records. First is made at 8th of the January with race time 01:14 and seconds is made at 9th of the Februay with the race time 01:14 and third is made at 10th of the July with 01:17 and forth one is made at 11 of the July with 01:16 and last one is made at 12 of the July with 01:15 so the order should be 01:14 with 8th January because it is the earliest and second is 9th Feb because it is the second best and third must be 12 of the Jul because its the third best time even it is made too late and

Comment: 4th should be 8th January and last one should be 10th July. In SQL query way: ORDER BY rec_time ASC, time ASC Also race_id is the ID of the race. Don't be bother with it.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**

With the new information I have another approach that you can try:

- First you need to know the best times for each *holder*:

  `SELECT id, holder, min(race_time) FROM race_time GROUP BY holder;`
- As you only need the top 5 let's put that constrain:

  `SELECT id, holder, min(race_time) FROM race_time GROUP BY holder ORDER BY min(race_time) ASC, time ASC LIMIT 5`
- Once you have this, you need only the *id* field so:

  `SELECT id FROM race_time GROUP BY holder ORDER BY min(race_time) ASC, time ASC LIMIT 5;`
- Finally you can get every column:

  `SELECT * FROM race_time WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM race_time GROUP BY holder ORDER BY min(race_time) ASC, time ASC LIMIT 5);`

This should give you the top 5 different holders according to the (updated) definition you gave for the best holders.

**Before**

*I leave here the previous answer because the comments would be nonsense without it*

Assuming *race* is the table name and *position* is 1 for the first in the race, 2 for the second, etc., here you have.

```
SELECT * FROM race ORDER BY position LIMIT 5;
```

This is a very basic query, you should go and do some [SQL tutorial](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+tutorial)

Comment: I do know how to make a sql query :D But this returns the same person twice as they do multiple best records. I want to get the top 5 record holders, not top 5 times.

Comment: Then you should go and edit your question and state that. Also define what is a "record holder" :-)

Comment: I also tried `SELECT holder, rec_time FROM racerecords WHERE race_id = 17 GROUP BY holder ORDER BY rec_time ASC LIMIT 5;` and it returns first person with their best record. If the first time record is inserted with holder A, it returns A's best race record even though it is not the best time among all racers. A record holder is the racers nickname :D

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify when a racer is 'the best'. When you define it as the racer with the best average position your query will become:

```
SELECT holder, AVG(position) AS average_position 
FROM race 
GROUP BY holder
ORDER BY AVG(position) ASC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: It should be based on record time (rec_time) and most early record (time). When someone does the same rec_time with a record already before it'd not be counted as a record. The older record must be still valid.